# R package install issue in Jupyter Notebook launched with Anaconda

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-kernel

I created an R environment in Anaconda and launched it using Jupyter Notebook. I am receiving the following error message when I attempt to install the R package "ggbeeswarm."

```
    install.packages("ggbeeswarm")

also installing the dependencies ‘farver’, ‘isoband’, ‘rlang’, 
‘scales’, ‘vctrs’, ‘cli’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘beeswarm’, ‘lifecycle’

Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘farver’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘isoband’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘beeswarm’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("ggbeeswarm"):
“installation of package ‘ggbeeswarm’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

My computer was recently wiped without a backup so I've had to reinstall a lot of programs. I have previously been able to easily execute my script in this way-- launching Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda and then running my script in an R kernel. I'm wondering if I made a mistake with some aspect of reinstalling along the way.

After reading some other posts, I also tried:

```
    install.packages("ggbeeswarm", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

and am receiving the same error message.

I also tried in terminal:

```
    conda install -c conda-forge r-ggbeeswarm
```

and received the following error:

```
Solving environment: / failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

I also tried

```
    conda install r-base
```

and got the following message:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully The following packages are causing the inconsistency: - conda-forge/osx-64::pystan==3.6.0=py39h6dc771e_0
```

so uninstalled pystan completely and tried again. Still no luck.

Comment: Apologies for accidentally deleting a helpful comment from a user @wayne. I had tried the suggestion provided previously but forgot to add it to the original post. I've added that now.

Comment: @Wayne I wonder if my issue is with installation of Anaconda. I tried the following in terminal: 

    conda install r-base
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/osx-64::pystan==3.6.0=py39h6dc771e_0


Do you have any suggestions for correct re-installation of Anaconda?

Comment: Yes, I installed Anaconda a few days ago. I can try uninstalling and re-installing. The error message from before was a mistake-- that was from running in the Jupyter Notebook but I meant to run it in terminal. I edited the post with the error message from terminal.

Comment: Oh okay. Then don't uninstall yet. I'm surprised `conda install -c conda-forge r-ggbeeswarm` fails. Maybe an R person will be able to see the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Just added some additional troubleshooting I tried to the original post- hoping someone is able to point me in the right direction!

Comment: The conda message says it is trying a flexible solve. Did that fail as well? Please share all the output you got

Comment: @shs it was running for almost an hour so I aborted it but I'll try to let it run overnight and see if it just needs more time